# How to count number of rows before an ID in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I need to count the total number of rows in a table before the certain row ID.

I have this query

```
select count (ClientID) 
FROM [Seek].[dbo].[seekClient] 
where ClientID < '12'
```

which works fine for the case of integer primary key, but I am not sure how to do that in case of GUID ??

Kindly help me in this case.

Thanks

Comment: How you tell which GUID is smaller than the other?

Comment: I woud say, this isn't possible without a second field with a date or id because you can't get the orde in which they where created from a GUID.

Comment: "before" is rather poorly defined here. If you need to know how many rows *pre-date* a particular row, then you ought to be storing the insertion date in a specific column for this purpose. If you need something else, you need to tell us what "before" means in this context. Tables don't have an inherent order.

Comment: By "before" I mean that I need to know that how many rows exists before the occurrence of the particular record in a table.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, this isn't possible, see [this link](http://www.ostyn.com/standards/docs/guids.htm). Most specifically:

> Globally unique identifiers are typically not human readable, and they
>   are not intended to be read or interpreted by humans

Long answer - what's the rest of your table structure? There may be a different way to do what you're trying to do (I would imagine it's possible using a date created field if you have one)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a different column (not id) that defines what you mean by 'before'. It might be, for example, a 'DateOfCreation', 'creation_date' etc. column.